# Prevent text selection on rapid button clicks

Tags: html, css

I have a slideshow with divs for "Previous" and "Next" buttons.

Inside the div is a character "<" or ">".

The problem is that when the buttons get clicked rapidly to scroll through the pictures, the text gets selected.

I tried a few CSS tricks to prevent the selecting of the buttons text but it usually just ends up selecting text further down the page. It's also not cross browser compatible without JS hacks.

If the div doesn't have a character in it, it works perfectly. I tried covering the div with the character with a transparent div, but it seems like as long as there's a character under it, text will get selected.

Any suggestion to prevent this? I'd rather the solution doesn't involve javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: Can i not just suggest removing the < and > tag and use an image ? A well titled image will actually be better that < > for accessibility

Comment: I recently changed the background images for a custom font for theming purposes. The < and > actually look like arrows.

Comment: @enkay please tell us if dominic's solution is working for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a button perhaps:

```
<button>&gt;</button>
```

Comment: Just thought of that too. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this can be done with css you have to make it browser specific so something like this should work if you assign it too your < text

```
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
```

Comment: That's the css tricks I mention in the post. It does work for the buttons, but it just ends up selecting text further down the page. Also not sure it works at all in IE without JS. Thanks though.

Comment: If the person using the site can and wants to copy some text, it will be impossible to see the selection using this method.